# Use here-string "<<<" in subprocess

Tags: python

I've written Python code to list volumes from bareos backup.

I don't know how to pass it to the subprocess:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("bconsole <<< 'list volumes'", shell=True)
```

when run program, return error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use `shell=True`. Read here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Comment: It seems that your `/bin/sh` doesn’t support herestrings. This is the case, for example, in Debian where `sh` isn’t bash but dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the input to the created process with `.communicate()` instead and *never* use `shell=True`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["bconsole",],  # and any other args
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # retain output
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,  # retain output
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,   # needed to pass to communicate
)
# instance representing the process is created, but waits for input
# now provide the input and run the process until it completes
out, err = p.communicate("list volumes".encode())  # suggest timeout too
# p.returncode now set
```

Comment: not passed "list volumes" to 'bconsole' command. i want to run excaltly like this in bash: "bconsole <<< 'list volumes' " it seems run like this: "bconsole 'list volumes' " without "<<<"

Comment: Ah, that's not quite how a heredoc works; is `'list volumes'` intended to be the input to `bconsole`?

Comment: A little review indicates that's the case .. let me adjust my answer for it

Comment: yes, 'list volumes' is input of ```bconsole```

Comment: Thanks, it Worked!!